# Pentaho Reporting - Prompting API - How to remove loading

Tags: reporting, field, loading, pentaho

For every field (parameter) in my report, when using the PUC (Report Viewer), the PUC refresh the screen. It take quite a time and most of the reports i made have about 3-6 fields.

Searching in Pentaho Docs, i found this link that tells something about the Prompting API: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Serv...+Prompting+API.

But I have read all related pages and didn't find how to disable this reloading. It says that this behavour is to enable custom loadings parameters (like Country and State), but for me it's not necessary to have this kind of fields.

How could i disable this option? Note that i am not talking about auto update REPORT on selection, but auto update PARAMETER FIELDS.

Do i need to change the source code of some project or i can do that just by xml setting? I am not a developer so if there is a XML or related file it would be easyer to me.

See that my problem is not the "report reload" when i change a field, but is that the PUC refresh the screen to "reload filter configuration", as in its documentation. What i whant to do is to be able to type every parameter on the screen without having to wait for this loading, as you may know, you can not use "TAB" to fill this parameters, because of this reloads.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same headache. I wonder why the parameters dont act like the ususal html form we have. I dont see how parameter by parameter refreshing is necessary. Refreshing should take place only when you click submit

Comment: Yes, but people from pentaho dont think like that. Follow this threat and comment there to help us convincing pentaho team that this should be a optional feature: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?152485-Remove-loading-on-every-field-for-Report-Viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that in the version i tried, pentaho dont suport disabling this feature...

Dont waste your time like me.

Answer (score 2):

The refresh is handled by the JavaScript frontend. You can find the code in our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform-plugin-reporting/blob/master/package-res/reportviewer/reportviewer-prompt.js) and in your "pentaho-solution/system/reporting" directory.

However, the easiest way to disable the auto-submit checkbox and/or to set the auto-submit attribute on the master-report to false. This should positively prevent updates until you press the submit button.

Comment: My problem is not the "report reload" when i change a field, but is that the PUC refresh the screen to "reload filter configuration", as in its documentation. What i whant to do is to be able to type every parameter on the screen without having to wait for this loading, as you may know, you can not use "TAB" to fill this parameters, because of this reloads. Setting this property that you said will only avoid reloading the "report" but not the screen after every field insertion. Please tell me if i am not clear yet.